# Repetitive evdi compile error in /var/log/syslog

Tags: kernel, displaylink

The series of messages listed below just repeats over and over in `/var/log/syslog`. I'm running Xubuntu 21.04 on a Dell Latitude 7390, and using a Dell D6000 dock with DisplayLink.

```
Jun 11 17:43:30 hbotha-Latitude-7390 systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6970.
Jun 11 17:43:30 hbotha-Latitude-7390 systemd[1]: Stopped DisplayLink Driver Service.
Jun 11 17:43:30 hbotha-Latitude-7390 systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Driver Service...
Jun 11 17:43:30 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274016]: modprobe: FATAL: Module evdi not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic
Jun 11 17:43:30 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274045]: Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
Jun 11 17:43:30 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274045]: Building module:
Jun 11 17:43:30 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274045]: cleaning build area...
Jun 11 17:43:31 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274045]: make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=5.11.0-18-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic/build/include KVERSION=5.11.0-18-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
Jun 11 17:43:31 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274696]: ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 5.2.14 not found
Jun 11 17:43:31 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274776]: Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-18-generic (x86_64)
Jun 11 17:43:31 hbotha-Latitude-7390 sh[1274776]: Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/make.log for more information.
Jun 11 17:43:31 hbotha-Latitude-7390 systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=10/n/a
Jun 11 17:43:31 hbotha-Latitude-7390 systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 11 17:43:31 hbotha-Latitude-7390 systemd[1]: Failed to start DisplayLink Driver Service.
```

What do the messages mean, and what do I need to do to resolve this (or debug it further)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the DisplayLink driver I had was failing to compile, which is a known issue for certain combinations of driver version & Linux version. Downloading & installing the latest version from synaptics.com fixed the issue.